# Foo<T> where T is interface or implementation

Tags: c#, generics

I have this:

```
var newFoo = new Foo<Car>();

DoSomething(newFoo);


void DoSomething(Foo inputFoo)
{
    if (inputFoo is Foo<IDrivable> f) Console.WriteLine("It is a Foo<IDrivable>.");
    else Console.WriteLine("Nope, not a Foo<IDrivable>.");
}

public abstract class Foo { }
public class Foo<T>:Foo { }
public interface IDrivable { }
public class Car : IDrivable { }
```

This prints `"Nope, not a Foo<IDrivable>"`.

Is it possible to perform a contravariant check on `T`  somehow? How do I refactor the above to print `"It is a Foo<IDrivable>"`given a `Foo<Car>`?

Comment: Is there a chance that you could tell more about the real example for this?

Answer (score 3):

You can check whether there is a generic parameter and whether (the first one) is assignable to `IDrivable`.

```
var firstTypeParameter = inputFoo.GetType().GenericTypeArguments.FirstOrDefault();
if (firstTypeParameter != null && firstTypeParameter.IsAssignableTo(typeof(IDrivable)))
    Console.WriteLine("It is a Foo<IDrivable>");
```

Edit:

As noted in a comment, a more elegant solution can be achieved if you're willing to introduce another interface:

```
public interface IFoo<out T> { }
public class Foo<T> : Foo, IFoo<T> { }
```

The check then becomes

```
if (inputFoo is IFoo<IDrivable> f) 
    Console.WriteLine("It is a Foo<IDrivable>.");
```

Regarding the comment:

*Of course, using IFoo has the limitation that T can only be used in output positions within that interface.*

That is accurate but also not relevant since the purpose of that interface is to make it less cumbersome to interpret metadata about `Foo<T>`. To understand that limitation, consider the following:

```
public interface IFoo<out T> 
{ 
    T ThisCompiles();
    // void ThisDoesNotCompile(T input);
}
public class Foo<T> : Foo, IFoo<T> 
{ 
    public T ThisCompiles() => default;
    public T ThisCompilesBecauseNotPartOfIFooInterface(T input) 
        => default;
}
```

The class can use `T` as an input or output parameter. Methods on `IFoo<T>` could only use `T` as an output parameter, but since no methods need be defined on that interface, that restriction is irrelevant.

Comment: Of course, using `IFoo<out T>` has the limitation that `T` can only be used in output positions within that interface.

Comment: I don't think that's relevant in this case, but still a good point to call out. I updated my answer to reflect your input.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
var newFoo = new Foo<Car>();

DoSomething(newFoo);


void DoSomething(Foo inputFoo)
{
    if (inputFoo.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Foo<>) && typeof(IDrivable).IsAssignableFrom(inputFoo.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0])) Console.WriteLine("It is a Foo<IDrivable>.");
    else Console.WriteLine("Nope, not a Foo<IDrivable>.");
}

public abstract class Foo { }
public class Foo<T>:Foo { }
public interface IDrivable { }
public class Car : IDrivable { }
```

Comment: Introducing covariant interface IFoo<out T> is more elegant solution.